# Add constraints to generic parameters in extension

Tags: swift, generics, dictionary, swift2, swift-extensions

I have this function:

```
func flatten<Key: Hashable, Value>(dict: Dictionary<Key, Optional<Value>>) -> Dictionary<Key, Value> {
    var result = [Key: Value]()
    for (key, value) in dict {
        guard let value = value else { continue }
        result[key] = value
    }
    return result
}
```

As you can see, it transforms a `[Key: Value?]` dictionary into a `[Key: Value]` one (without the optional).

I wanted to extend the `Dictionary` class with a new method only for classes which value is an `Optional` of any type, but I am unable to add constraints to the generic parameters of the dictionary.

This is what I tried:

```
extension Dictionary where Value: Optional<Any> {
    func flatten() -> [Key: Any] {
        var result = [Key: Any]()
        for (key, value) in self {
            guard let value = value else { continue }
            result[key] = value
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

But fails with error:

```
Type 'Value' constrained to non-protocol type 'Optional<Any>'
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this code in the Playground:

```
// make sure only `Optional` conforms to this protocol
protocol OptionalEquivalent {
  typealias WrappedValueType
  func toOptional() -> WrappedValueType?
}

extension Optional: OptionalEquivalent {
  typealias WrappedValueType = Wrapped

  // just to cast `Optional<Wrapped>` to `Wrapped?`
  func toOptional() -> WrappedValueType? {
    return self
  }
}

extension Dictionary where Value: OptionalEquivalent {
  func flatten() -> Dictionary<Key, Value.WrappedValueType> {
    var result = Dictionary<Key, Value.WrappedValueType>()
    for (key, value) in self {
      guard let value = value.toOptional() else { continue }
      result[key] = value
    }
    return result
  }
}

let a: [String: String?] = ["a": "a", "b": nil, "c": "c", "d": nil]
a.flatten() //["a": "a", "c": "c"]
```

Because you cannot specify an exact type in the `where` clause of a protocol extension, one way you may detect exactly the `Optional` type is to make `Optional` UNIQUELY conforms to a protocol (say `OptionalEquivalent`).

In order to get the wrapped value type of the `Optional`, I defined a typealias `WrappedValueType` in the custom protocol `OptionalEquivalent` and then made an extension of Optional, assgin the `Wrapped` to `WrappedValueType`, then you can get the type in the flatten method.

Note that the `sugarCast` method is just to cast the `Optional<Wrapped>` to `Wrapped?`(which is exactly the same thing), to enable the usage `guard` statement.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Rob Napier 's comment I have simplified & renamed the sugarCast() method and renamed the protocol to make it more understandable.

Comment: You can more easily implement `sugarCast()` as `return self`. I personally recommend calling this protocol `OptionalConvertible` and `sugarCast()` `toOptional()`, but your way is fine, too.

Comment: That's a very creative way to workaround generic limitations. I'll probably use it in more places. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You can do it in a simpler way. This works with Swift 4:

```
extension Dictionary {
    func flatten<Wrapped>() -> [Key: Wrapped] where Value == Optional<Wrapped> {
         return filter { $1 != nil }.mapValues { $0! }
    }
}
```

If you don't like the use of higher order functions or need compatibility with previous versions of Swift you can do this as well:

```
extension Dictionary {
    func flatten<Wrapped>() -> [Key: Wrapped] where Value == Optional<Wrapped> {
        var result: [Key: Wrapped] = [:]
        for (key, value) in self {
            guard let value = value else { continue }
            result[key] = value
        }
        return result
    }
}
```