# How can I create an inline dictionary in Swift while omitting potentially nil optionals as values?

Tags: ios, swift

I have some optional properties (a small sample of the actual properties in the class, for brevity):

```
var assigneeIds: [Int]?
var locationIds: [Int]?
var searchQuery: String?
```

I need to convert these to JSON. I've been advised by the maintainer of the API to not supply keys with nil values, so my `toJson` method looks like this:

```
var result: [String: AnyObject] = [:]
if let assigneeIds = assigneeIds {
    result["assignee_ids"] = assigneeIds
}
if let locationIds = locationIds {
    result["location_ids"] = locationIds
}
if let searchQuery = searchQuery {
    result["search_query"] = searchQuery
}
return result
```

This doesn't feel very "Swift" - it's quite verbose. Ideally, I'd like it to look similar to the following - with the exception of it *not setting the key* if the optional has no value. The below code will still set the key, along with an `NSNull` value which gets serialised to `"assignee_ids": null` in the resulting JSON. Presumably I can configure the serializer to omit `NSNull` values, but I've encountered this pattern elsewhere and am interested to see if there's a better way.

```
return [
    "assignee_ids" : self.assigneeIds ?? NSNull(),
    "location_ids" : self.locationIds ?? NSNull(),
    "search_query" : self.searchQuery ?? NSNull()
]
```

How can I skip creating `key->NSNull` entries when building an inline dictionary in this way?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/33436927/97337 which may be exactly the solution you really want, and if not, can be trivially adapted to your problem.

Comment: That's a creative solution! Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually don't need to unwrap the values at all, since the value won't be set in the dictionary when it's nil. Example:

```
var dict : [String : Any] = [:]

dict["a"] = 1      // dict = ["a" : 1]
dict["b"] = nil    // dict = ["a" : 1]
dict["a"] = nil    // dict = [:]
```

You can also CMD-Click on the bracket and look at the definition of the Dictionary subscript:

```
public subscript (key: Key) -> Value?
```

this means you get an Optional (whether it exists or not) and you set an Optional (to set it or remove it)

Your code will look like this:

```
var result: [String: AnyObject] = [:]
result["assignee_ids"] = assigneeIds
result["location_ids"] = locationIds
result["search_query"] = searchQuery
return result
```

Comment: Man, this is brilliant, how did I never realise this?

Comment: @DannyBravo I have to admit it's not really intuitive to remove/not set values by setting them to nil :)

Comment: Well, this is obvious - I _did_ realise you can remove values by setting them to nil, I just never considered creating the result as a `var`. Seems I was focused on setting the values inline at declaration.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
return [
    "assignee_ids" : self.assigneeIds ?? NSNull(),
    "location_ids" : self.locationIds ?? NSNull(),
    "search_query" : self.searchQuery ?? NSNull()
].filter { key, val -> Bool in !(val is NSNull) }
```

Comment: I like this solution, though I'm having trouble getting Xcode to accept it in my project. `filter { $1 != NSNull() }` works perfectly in a Playground of course...

Comment: I just wrote it quickly on a Playground, I can't think of a reason it wouldn't work on the project, though.

Comment: I think you have to write  `.filter { (key, value) -> Bool in return value != NSNull() }` to make this compile. The problem however is that the result is an array of (key, value)  tuples, not a dictionary.

Comment: Ah, close. `.filter { key, val -> Bool in !(val is NSNull) }` - note the `is` keyword. It wasn't keen on comparing `AnyObject` with `NSNull` using equality operators. Of course, the result is still an array so this won't work after all.