# Dictionary extension to convert nil values to NSNull

Tags: swift, generics, nsdictionary

Since you can't cast a `Dictionary<String, AnyObject?>` into a `NSDictionary` directly, I want to write a `Dictionary` extension that will do that conversion (substituting `NSNull` for any `nil`s).

But in order to do that, my `Dictionary` extension must be constrained to dicts whose values are `Optional<T> where T:AnyObject`. How do I write the type constraint for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add nil to a dict. So you have to force it in there with a cast to `someType?` just so you have a key.

Borrowing from this [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33436199/add-constraints-to-generic-parameters-in-extension) for the OptionalConvertible solution:

```
protocol OptionalConvertible {
    typealias WrappedValueType = AnyObject
    func toOptional() -> WrappedValueType?
}

extension Optional: OptionalConvertible {
    typealias WrappedValueType = Wrapped

    // just to cast `Optional<Wrapped>` to `Wrapped?`
    func toOptional() -> WrappedValueType? {
        return self
    }
}
```

---

```
extension Dictionary where Value: OptionalConvertible, Key: NSCopying {
    //dict: Dictionary<Key, Optional<Value>>
    func convertToNSDictionary() -> NSDictionary {

        let mutableDict : NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()

        for key in self.keys {
            if let maybeValue = self[key] {
                if let value = maybeValue.toOptional() {
                    mutableDict[key] = value as? AnyObject
                } else {
                    mutableDict[key] = NSNull()
                }
            }
        }
        return mutableDict

    }
}
```

---

```
var optionalObject : UIView? = nil

var dict : [NSString:AnyObject?] = [:]
dict["alpha"] = 1
dict["beta"] = 2
dict["delta"] = optionalObject as AnyObject? // force a nil into the dict

dict // ["beta": {Some 2}, "alpha": {Some 1}, "delta": nil]

let nsdict = dict.convertToNSDictionary() // ["alpha": 1, "beta": 2, "delta": {NSObject}]
```

---

**Or a more practical approach :**

```
extension NSDictionary {

    static func fromDictionary<Key: Hashable, Value:AnyObject where Key: NSCopying>(dictionary:Dictionary<Key, Value>) -> NSDictionary {

        let mutableDict : NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()

        for key in dictionary.keys {
            if let value = dictionary[key] {
                mutableDict[key] = value
            } else {
                mutableDict[key] = NSNull()
            }
        }
        return mutableDict
    }

    static func fromDictionary<Key: Hashable, Value:AnyObject where Key: NSCopying>(dict: Dictionary<Key, Optional<Value>>) -> NSDictionary {

        let mutableDict : NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()

        for key in dict.keys {
            if let maybeValue = dict[key] {
                if let value = maybeValue {
                    mutableDict[key] = value
                } else {
                    mutableDict[key] = NSNull()
                }
            }
        }
        return mutableDict
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but there's no point to this being a Dictionary extension; your functions might as well be globals. A member function would be a much better way to implement this, hence my question about type constraints.

Comment: @phu This function does exactly what you wanted. What broader constraints should it work for?

Comment: I didn't ask for you to write the function itself; please re-read my original question. I'm asking about **type constraints**. For example, `extension Dictionary where Value:AnyObject` would define an extension that only applies to dicts whose values implement `AnyObject`. I want to know how to create an extension that applies to dicts whose values are `T? where T:AnyObject`.

Comment: @phu optionals and generics / constraints don't mix well. They might one day. Updated the answer more specific constraints.

Comment: Your new answer is closer, but it's still only constraining the type to `Optional`s. If the constraints I wanted aren't possible, I'd like to understand why— ideally via some Swift documentation that explains the limitation in detail.

Comment: @phu don't stare yourself blind at constraints. Just like generics they tend to complicate things more than they simplify. Getting the correct result is much more important.