# Swift 3: Cant unwrap optional from Dictionary?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, option-type

Ok I don't know what is going on here. I have a dictionary of Strings below:

```
var animals = ["max": "z", "Royal": nil] //store key pairs
```

and I am unable to print the value of the value in the key value pair without it printing "Optional" along with it.

I have tried using `!` `!!` and casting as a String as well as the following:

```
var animalsToReturn = [String]()

        if animals[selected]! != nil
        {
            if let pairName = animals[selected]
            {
                print("\(pairName)")

                print("has pair",selected, animals[selected]!)

//trying to append to another array here
                animalsToReturn.append("\(animals[selected]!)")
                animalsToReturn.append(selected)
            }
        }
        else {
            print("no pair")
        }
```

I check to make sure the value isn't nil, so it won't crash if I unwrap. But this is what is printed and the word Optional is appended to my other array:

[image]

Comment: An explicit `nil` value in a dictionary is nonsense because `nil` value means *key is missing* and by definition you can remove a key by assigning `nil`.

Comment: You have a dictionary whose values are `Optional<String>` because you are storing `nil` as a value. Thus, you have to double-unwrap when you don't get `nil` And, as vadian has said, you run into the difficulty that `nil` is already the not-found marker. It would be better, if something is `nil`, not to store it in the dictionary at all! By the way, Apple has a very nice blog entry on this topic: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=12 This discusses how to make a different not-found marker.

Comment: Related: [Two (or more) optionals in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27225232/two-or-more-optionals-in-swift).

Answer (score 4):

You have included `nil` as a value, so the type of your dictionary's value is not String but `Optional<String>`. But fetching a value by key from a dictionary is itself an Optional. Therefore:

- If your entry is present and is ultimately a String, it is an `Optional<Optional<String>>` and you have to unwrap it twice.
- If your entry is present and is ultimately `nil`, it is an Optional wrapping `nil`.
- If your entry is not present, it is `nil`.

You can readily test this as follows:

```
func test(_ selected:String) {
    var animals = ["max": "z", "Royal": nil]
    if let entry = animals[selected] { // attempt to find
        if let entry = entry { // attempt to double-unwrap
            print("found", entry)
        } else {
            print("found nil")
        }
    } else {
        print("not found")
    }
}
test("max") // found z
test("Royal") // found nil
test("glop") // not found
```

Contemplation of that example will answer your original question, namely "I don't know what is going on here".

Answer (score 1):

`animals[selected]` is a `Optional<Optional<String>>` because you're storing `nil`. You can:

1. Double unwrap your value either by using `if let` or `!` twice.
2. Change the type of your dictionary to `[String: String]` (instead of `[String: String?]`), and thus avoiding `nil` values.
3. Flatten the dictionary, removing `nil` values, and then accessing it as a `[String: String]`

You can flatten the dictionary using the code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33436199/add-constraints-to-generic-parameters-in-extension).

Answer (score 0):

Please enclose that in bracket and use double unwrapping. try this : -

```
animalsToReturn.append("\((animals[selected])!!)")
```

[image: tried in playground]

Answer (score 0):

```
func addAnimal(_ animal: String) {
    guard let animal = animals[animal] else {
        print("No pair")
        return
    }
    animalsToReturn.append(animal ?? "")
}
```